# updating data frame rows based on previous rows

Tags: r

Given the data frame below (simple time series sorted on time):

```
 time groups      value     value1
1    1      b -0.6264538  0.7383247
2    2      b  0.1836433  0.5757814
3    3      b -0.8356286 -0.3053884
4    1      a  1.5952808  1.5117812
5    2      a  0.3295078  0.3898432
6    3      a -0.8204684 -0.6212406
7    4      a  0.4874291 -2.2146999
```

for each groups (a or b) and for each row in this group (at time t), I want to update each row as the sum of the current row (at time t) and a scaled version of the previous row (at time t-1) (if previous row doesn't exist, don't update)

The tricky part is that once a row gets updated, the updated version (and not the original one) should be used for updating the next row. I could achieve this by looping over the time and groups. I was wondering if there's a more efficient way to do this using lag()/dplyr/...?

```
set.seed(1)
data <- data.frame(time = c(1:3, 1:4),
                   groups = c(rep(c("b", "a"), c(3, 4))),
                   value = rnorm(7), value1=rnorm(7))

alfa = 0.1
for (id in unique(data$groups)){
  data_tmp <- data[data$groups==id,]
  for (i in 2:nrow(data_tmp)){
    for (col in colnames(data)[-(1:2)]){
      data[data$groups==id,][i,][col] = data[data$groups==id,][i,][col] + alfa* data[data$groups==id,][i-1,][col]
    }
  }
}
```

Desired output:

```
 time groups      value     value1
1    1      b -0.6264538  0.7383247
2    2      b  0.1209979  0.6496138
3    3      b -0.8235288 -0.2404270
4    1      a  1.5952808  1.5117812
5    2      a  0.4890359  0.5410214
6    3      a -0.7715648 -0.5671384
7    4      a  0.4102726 -2.2714137
```

Comment: [`zoo::rollsum`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/zoo/index.html) might help.

Comment: Your expected output suggests you want the original values to be used in the lag instead of the updated ones.

Comment: Your `data$value[3]` does not match your assertion. If it should be going off of the *updated version* of the previous value, then `$value[1]` is -0.626, `$value[2]` is `0.184 + 0.1(-0.626)` or 0.121, and `$value[3]` is `-0.836 + 0.1(0.121)` or -0.824 (not 0.817).

Comment: @MikeH. and r2evans thanks for catching that! there was a slight overlook which I fixed it in the code and in the desired output!

Comment: @Peyman Isn't the last line wrong too?

Comment: @PLapointe one more bug :/ modified my code/OP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're asking for is essentially an exponentially-weighted moving sum. There are some packages that supply functions supporting that concept, but here's a quick function I use on some of my stuff:

```
EWS <- function(x, alfa = 0.1) sum(x * (alfa ^ (length(x):1 - 1)))
EWMS <- function(x, width, FUN, ...) {
  FUN <- match.fun(FUN)
  lenx <- length(x)
  for (i in tail(seq_along(x), n = 1-width)) {
    x[i] <- do.call(FUN, c(list(x[ max(1, i-width+1):i ]), list(...)))
  }
  x
}
```

(`EWS` can trivially be changed to use `mean` or another vector function.)

Simple proof of concept. The EWS of 1:3 (with an `alfa` of 0.1) should be

```
3*(10^0) + 2*(10^1) + 1*(10^2)
3*(1) + 2*(0.1) + 1*(0.01)
### R-ified/simplified to
3:1 * 10^-(0:2)
# [1] 3.00 0.20 0.01
sum(3:1 * 10^-(0:2))
# [1] 3.21
EWS(1:3, alfa=0.1)
# [1] 3.21
```

assuming that "3" is the most-recent data, and "2" and "1" are the past. (This can easily be changed, it's just a starting point.)

The moving part is similarly justified. I find a spreadsheet a straight-forward way to demonstrate what *should* be happening:

[image: screenshot of excel formulas]

```
EWMS(1:5, width=2, EWS)
# [1] 1.0000 2.1000 3.2100 4.3210 5.4321
EWMS(1:5, width=3, EWS)
# [1] 1.0000 2.1000 3.2200 4.3430 5.4665
```

So adapting this to @PLapointe's `dplyr` recommendation:

```
library(dplyr)
dat %>%
  group_by(groups) %>%
  mutate_each(funs(EWMS(., width=2, EWS)), -time) %>%
  ungroup()
# # A tibble: 7 × 4
#    time groups      value     value1
#   <int>  <chr>      <dbl>      <dbl>
# 1     1      b -0.6264538  0.7383247
# 2     2      b  0.1209979  0.6496139
# 3     3      b -0.8235288 -0.2404270
# 4     1      a  1.5952808  1.5117812
# 5     2      a  0.4890359  0.5410213
# 6     3      a -0.7715648 -0.5671385
# 7     4      a  0.4102726 -2.2714137
```

Comment: That's awesome.

Comment: Thanks @r2evans for the very flexible solution! I was exactly looking for a way to have customized moving average and this helped a lot!!

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to do that with `dplyr`:

```
df1<-read.table(text="time groups      value     value1
1    1      b -0.6264538  0.7383247
2    2      b  0.1836433  0.5757814
3    3      b -0.8356286 -0.3053884
4    1      a  1.5952808  1.5117812
5    2      a  0.3295078  0.3898432
6    3      a -0.8204684 -0.6212406
7    4      a  0.4874291 -2.2146999",header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)


alfa  <- 0.1
func <-function(x){x+alfa*dplyr::lag(x,default = 0)}

library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
group_by(groups) %>%
mutate_each(funs(func(.)),-time)

   time groups      value     value1
  <int>  <chr>      <dbl>      <dbl>
1     1      b -0.6264538  0.7383247
2     2      b  0.1209979  0.6496139
3     3      b -0.8172643 -0.2478103
4     1      a  1.5952808  1.5117812
5     2      a  0.4890359  0.5410213
6     3      a -0.7875176 -0.5822563
7     4      a  0.4053823 -2.2768240
```

Comment: @r2evans I'm using the dplyr version of `lag`. I'm using it all the time. I think this is right as I have exactly the same result as desired by OP.

Comment: I realized it was the same after I sent the comment. I think either the OP assertion is mis-stated or the desired output is incorrect. Either way, until clarification, I'll retract my comment :-)

Comment: @r2evans apologies! there was a slight overlook in my code/OP which I fixed it

Comment: @PLapointe thanks for the help! As I mentioned, the desired output will be using the last updated row! Any idea how to refer to this in your func?